# netty EventExecutorGroup Thread repeat execution

Tags: multithreading, netty

Recently,I use netty to build a server program but I meet a A difficult problem,
sometime when my program receive a connection, it will use multiple threads to handler the same connection.

For example,when the clients connects to the server,the clients gives server-side data A, then there will be multiple different threads that receive data A and process it,this makes my database often have the same data inserted

How can I solve this problem?

my code:

```
private int port;
private Conf MyConf;
public static String Path;

public ChiconyServerBootstrap(String Path)
{

    try
    {
        MyConf = new Conf(Path);
        port = MyConf.getPort();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start()
{
    ServerBootstrap serverbootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    NioEventLoopGroup connect_group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    NioEventLoopGroup io_group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    final EventExecutorGroup work_group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);

    try
    {
        serverbootstrap.group(connect_group, io_group);
        serverbootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        serverbootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
        {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
            {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(work_group, new WorkHandler());
            }
        });

        serverbootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 60);
        serverbootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        ChannelFuture future = serverbootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)).sync();
        future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        connect_group.shutdownGracefully();
        io_group.shutdownGracefully();
        work_group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChiconyServerBootstrap server;  
    Path = "./Conf/config.properties";
    server = new ChiconyServerBootstrap(Path);
    server.start();
}
```

The WorkHandler in NioEventLoopGroup:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
{       
    //Initialization parameter
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception
{
    //Accept the parameters from the client
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
{       
    //Perform business logic, data insert into database
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) 
{   

}
```

Comment: Netty is designed to work with multiple threads, this is also needed to get the most performance from an NIO environment, as other wise most cores threads are doing nothing. You could make it single threaded by using the `new NioEventLoopGroup(1);` constructor however

Comment: Please show your "full" WorkHandler